# Fatal error: In Magento 2.0 Theme installation

Tags: themes, fatal-error, magento-2.0

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\oyejorge\less.php\lib\Less\Visitor\processExtends.php on line 445
in theme installation in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are receving this error then run this command please
" php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy "